# Why I cant use Document class from Itext7 properly?

Tags: java, itext7

```
File file = new File("D/project");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document;
```

`Unknown class document`
The import that it offered is strange as well but I didnt have any other choice:

```
import static com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.Document;
```

I tried to re-add the Itext library, even different version but it just don't want to work for me

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong import statement here. Use the following one

```
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
```

You've only included the `kernel-7.x.x.jar` dependency. `Document` is available in the `layout-7.x.x.jar`. You've to include that dependency. If you've maven project then you can add all iText7 core dependencies by adding the following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
  <version>${itext.version}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise you can add the corresponding jars on the classpath.

iText7 core consists of `kernel`, `layout`, `sign` etc. For more details you can see the pom having those dependencies included. ex:
[itext7-core-7.1.10.pom](https://repo.itextsupport.com/ui/repos/tree/PomView/releases/com/itextpdf/itext7-core/7.1.10/itext7-core-7.1.10.pom)

Comment: I tried to use this one but its doesnt find the path. Is my libary maybe missing some parts?

Comment: Updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Document is a class. After adding the dependency in the pom file and installing it, and also "import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;"
Then change to "Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);"

Comment: Your answer will be easier to understand with code formatting instead of quotes.